# Foreach using 2 arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

```
public class Cidade {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhos;

public class Vizinhos {
private String namev;
private Distancias distancia;

public class Distancias {
private float reta;
private float rodovia;
```

//

```
ArrayList<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList<>();
```

//

```
            for(Cidade cidade: cidades){
            System.out.println(cidade.getName());
        }//this work easy
```

i can do a foreach like that?

```
       ArrayList<Vizinhos> v
        for(Cidade cidade: cidades){
            System.out.println(cidade.getName());
        for(String namev: v){

        }}
```

or something like that, how the for, will know what Obj **Vizinhos** he is accessing
because i'm accessing the Arraylist *Cidades* made of Obj **Cidade** Alright?
and how i say access the Arraylist *Vizinhos* of this Obj **Cidade**. for print each **vizinho** in the Arraylist *Vizinhos* of the obj **Cidade**

Summing up i need print all info in the Arraylist vizinhos using some index of the OBJ Cidade or something like that

Comment: No, that second foreach loop can't work, as `Vizinhos` isn't a array/list but a type.

Comment: i edit, look now what i'm trying to do, how the loop will know what Arraylist V he's accessing? or will access the arraylist the right Arraylist?? and stop look the syntax pls i know it's wrong it just the idea what i need to do, if i had did the right syntax i would not be here xD

Comment: I guess, you are trying to do something with the ArrayList `vizinhos` inside the current `cidade` object, right? Then you will have to make `vizinhos` **public** instead of **private**.

Comment: u can do an example of this?i had understand nothing

Comment: Sorry, but I am afraid, you need to learn more about OOP first. I maybe understand your problem, but it would take us both too much time to clarify, what you are trying to accomplish and how to do it.

Comment: k, then you have to change the line `private ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhos;` to `public ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhos;` to tell the system that *vizinhos* is supposed to be accessed from outside the object and then you can write `for(Vizinhos vizinho: cidade.vizinhos){` to acces the arrayList of the current `vizinhos` object and iterate over its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Cidade cidade : cidades ) {
        System.out.println(cidade.getName());
        ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhosList = cidade.getVizinhos();
        for ( Vizinhos vizinhos : vizinhosList ) {
            System.out.println(vizinhos.getNamev());
            System.out.println(vizinhos.getDistancia().getReta());
            System.out.println(vizinhos.getDistancia().getRodovia());
        }
    }
```

I think you want to this on how ever i do not understand your problem correctly.
I think you want to access cidades object have Vizinhos array list you can do it like above.

```
 public class Cidade {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhos;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ArrayList<Vizinhos> getVizinhos() {
    return vizinhos;
}

public void setVizinhos( ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhos ) {
    this.vizinhos = vizinhos;
}
```

}

public class Vizinhos {

```
private String namev;
private Distancias distancia;

public String getNamev() {
    return namev;
}

public void setNamev( String namev ) {
    this.namev = namev;
}

public Distancias getDistancia() {
    return distancia;
}

public void setDistancia( Distancias distancia ) {
    this.distancia = distancia;
}
```

}

public class Distancias {

```
private float reta;
private float rodovia;

public float getReta() {
    return reta;
}

public void setReta( float reta ) {
    this.reta = reta;
}

public float getRodovia() {
    return rodovia;
}

public void setRodovia( float rodovia ) {
    this.rodovia = rodovia;
}
```

}

Comment: NICE, that line bro "    ArrayList<Vizinhos> vizinhosList = cidade.getVizinhos();" that's stance i was forgetting ty a lot bro, and i had the classes already